# new to Bash - keep getting Illegal option error

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-13.04

I'm quite new to ubuntu and bash scripting and wanted to know why I might be getting this error when using GETOPTS.

here is the code I use to run it.

```
sh /home/ubuntu/Desktop/test.sh -f /home/u/Desktop/ -p 'TEST'
```

I think i'm calling the script correctly, and it should search for the term I enter as a search term using grap. but for some reason it doesn't. Any advice on what I can do as a general rule when working with grep would also be appreciated, thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

valid=0
file_arg=""
display_help=""
column=""
pattern=""

while getopts f:d:s:m: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        d)  display_help=$OPTARG
            ;;
        f)  file_arg=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)  column=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)  pattern=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)  valid=1
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $valid -eq "0" ]
then
    if [ $pattern != "" ]
    then
        cat $file_arg | grep $pattern
    else
        cat $file
    fi
else
    echo -n "Usage: FILE -f <name> | COLUMN -> -c <name> | HELP -> -d | PATTERN -> -p <expression>"
fi
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `getopts` you not specify `p` option you only have `f:d:s:m:` options.

I think you mean `p` instead `m` or vice versa.

It should `f:d:s:m:p:` or `f:d:s:p:`

Answer (score 10):

You should also consider the error supression and error handling features of `getopts`.

If the **very first character** of the option string is a colon (`:`) then `getopts` will not report errors and instead will provide a means of handling the errors yourself. Two additional characters can then be used within your case conditional handling:

- `?` If an invalid option is entered then `$opt` will be set to `?` and `$OPTARG` will hold the invalid character, e.g. if `-z` was used, which is not in your option string, then `$OPTARG` will be set to `z`.
- `:` If a required additional argument is omitted by the user then `$opt` will be set to `:` and `$OPTARG` will hold the command character, e.g. if `-p` was used instead of `-p arg` then `$OPTARG` will be set to `p`.

If this is implemented then the catch-all of `*` becomes redundant and should be removed. Note: If you leave it in and it is above either `?` or `:` then you'll be asking for problems. Also make sure the `?` is escaped like this `\?)`.

Hope this helps.

```
# Note the addition of the inital colon before 'f'.
while getopts :f:d:c:p: opt;
do
    case $opt in
        d)  display_help=$OPTARG
            ;;
        f)  file_arg=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)  column=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)  pattern=$OPTARG
            ;;

        # Option error handling.

        \?) valid=0
            echo "An invalid option has been entered: $OPTARG"
            ;;

        :)  valid=0
            echo "The additional argument for option $OPTARG was omitted."
            ;;

        # This is now redundant:
        # *)  valid=0
        #     break
        #     ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: If the `?` is not escaped, then it matches anything and you never get to the `:` case, so missing args are reported as invalid options.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mark. Useful knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of other issues with your script, as Jayesh mentioned, you need to include all parameters for getopt but you also need to be careful with string comparisons, here's a couple more fixes with suggestions:

(See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html for string comparison info)

```
#!/bin/bash

# switch around valid, convention is 1 == true and 0 == false
valid=1
file_arg=""
display_help=""
column=""
pattern=""

# getopt patterns need to match following case statement
while getopts f:d:c:p: opt;
do
    case $opt in
        d)  display_help=$OPTARG
            ;;
        f)  file_arg=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)  column=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)  pattern=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)  valid=0
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

# changed value to reflect true false convention
if [ "$valid" -eq "1" ]
then
    # string comparison in bash should be done using specific operators
    if [ -n "$pattern" ]
    then
        cat $file_arg | grep $pattern
    else
        # typo, this should be file_arg?
        cat $file_arg
    fi
else
    echo -n "Usage: FILE -f <name> | COLUMN -> -c <name> | HELP -> -d | PATTERN -> -p <expression>"
fi
```